# unit testing fading out directive - cannot see the right CSS class added -angular & jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, ng-animate

i'm trying to test the very simple directive i have made.

```
.directive('cssnotification', [ '$timeout', function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict:'A',
    link:function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch('success',function(newVal ,oldVal){

            if(newVal){                                
                $timeout(function(){                        

                         scope.success = false;                                                      

                },1000);
            }
        },true)
    }  
}
 }])
```

This directive makes some element to be visible for 1 second and after that - fades it out.
(here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FPvsZ/3/) that demonstrates the problem)

I know that for perform the fadingOut animation angular should add "ng-hide-add" class to the element, and that is that i'm trying to test. In the browser it works (remove angular-mocks from fiddler and it will run) but in unit tests - this test fails for some reason.

I guess it has something to do with injecting of ng-animate...

Thanks forwards

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution: to wait some time until nganimate adds the class:

```
      $timeout(function(){
          expect(e.hasClass('ng-hide-add')).toEqual(true);
      },100)
```

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FPvsZ/4/)