# How can I pause an AngularJS directive unit tests in such a way that I can observe and interact with the UI?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-mock

## Motivation

When testing directives; sometimes assertions fail in non-obvious ways, stack traces are not helpful and inspecting local variables while paused on a breakpoint with Chrome Developer Tools hides the forest behind the tree.

This is when I wish I was able to pause a unit test (possibly with `iit` or `ddescribe`) and poke around the UI of the directive to narrow down the faulty behavior.

## So far

I have been able to achieve this with KnockoutJS before and found it to be an exceedingly useful technique in complicated scenarios. Now I would like to do the same for AngularJS.

- I have found that I can attach the element I `$compile`d with Angular to the html body, and that makes it visible, however I cannot interact with it, as if all the bindings were turned off.
- Upon closer inspection I found that while running a test case (an `it` block) everything seems to be in order, as soon as the test case finishes all the event listeners vanish from the corresponding DOM elements — like `click` listener on a `<button ng-click="...">`.
- After some digging I found that deep inside [angular-mocks.js:1965](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks/blob/01e2f4aea1c4df54118b0572bb618b89a9436f8b/angular-mocks.js#L1967) there is an `afterEach` block that calls `.off()` to turn off DOM event listeners at two places:

  - [`injector.get('$rootElement').off();`](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks/blob/01e2f4aea1c4df54118b0572bb618b89a9436f8b/angular-mocks.js#L1973) and
  - [`handle && angular.element(handle.elem).off();`](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks/blob/01e2f4aea1c4df54118b0572bb618b89a9436f8b/angular-mocks.js#L1946) (via `angular.mock.clearDataCache();`)
- When I comment out the two `.off()` lines, voilà, the appended directives jump to life in the DOM!

*Note: While the version of angular-mocks I link to (`v1.2.10-build.2148+sha.fced1c0`) is not bleeding-edge, newer ones only seem to differ in line numbers being shifted when it comes to this part.*

## Question

Is there a better (more supported, less ad-hoc, and/or less hackish) way to achieve what I am trying to do? If so, how?

### Edit: versions

- Karma 0.10.9
- Jasmine 1.3.1
- Angular Mocks v1.2.10-build.2148+sha.fced1c0
- AngularJS 1.2.10-build.2148+sha.fced1c0

Comment: Am I misreading, or did you neglect to tell us what unit testing framework / tool you're using? Usually my unit tests are UI independent.  If you need UI interaction, perhaps you need something like Selenium which is a UI Testing too.

Comment: @JeffryHouser Edited the question to include them.

Comment: @JeffryHouser To address the second part of your comment: When __unit testing__ AngularJS directives, it is possible to check the state of the encapsulated DOM. Let alone possible it is sometimes downright desirable. Example: [`expect(element.html()).toContain("lidless, wreathed in flame, 2 times");`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#directives). So it is not integration tests that I am talking about, and therefore Selenium would be of no use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unit testing fading out directive - cannot see the right CSS class added -angular & jasmine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781057/unit-testing-fading-out-directive-cannot-see-the-right-css-class-added-angula)